# Maven not looking for plugin in repository

Tags: java, maven, jetty

I have a small problem in which I'm looking to use both the default Maven repository and another repository for my organization. When I go to compile it throws a whole list of warnings that packages aren't available. Then at the very end of the error it list places that it looked. It checks my local repository (.m2/) and my organization repository but it won't check the original default repository. Has anyone run into this issue before?

Comment: Is your org repository mirroring the central (default) repository?  Can you post relevant snippets of repository configuration?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the repositories that are configured in your MAVEN_HOME/conf/settings.xml file.  All the repos you are using should be listed in there.

You will need this config file to include your organizations repo, but you will have to add the apache one as well when you override the default.